# Ubiquiti UniFi Wireless bridging over two floors

Tags: ubiquiti, bridging

I need a setup like this:

```
+----------+     +----+
| Router   | --- | AP |
| (DHCP ?) |     |    |
+----------+     +----+
                   |
                   | wireless
                   |
+--------+       +----+
| PC     | ----- | AP |
+--------+       +----+
```

Is there a way to use Ubiquiti UniFi for this setup? Because some of them have a secondary LAN port.

Note:

- I cant use a wire
- I dont want to use DLAN

Comment: Both WAPs on the same floor?

Comment: whoopsie, I meant two floors

Comment: Wireless doesn't travel through floors very well; steel and concrete will block much of the signal. You will probably get slow speeds.

Comment: This is where you really ant to get a wireless site survey. Your company can hire and expert to perform this for you, and you will get a better idea if this is even worth pursuing.

Comment: The wireless connection isnt the problem. I want to know if rthis works with UniFi.

Comment: Assuming it does, my comment (not an answer) is to warn you that you may be very disappointed with the results. Before you even get to the point of asking if it works with your WAPs, you should determine if it is physically possible in your office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. There is no way to configure an Ubiquiti WAP in Unifi to act as a client. The main gigabit port is to be connected to the network infrastructure, the secondary port is just a pass-through port, and the wireless component acts as an access point as it's configured via Unifi.

Even when you SSH into these devices about the only configuration change you can make to them is to set the which Unifi server they should contact for configuration information.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there any other hardware in the Ubiquiti universe for bridging over wlan?

Comment: If you are dead set on using Ubiquiti I believe the airmax product line can be used for wifi bridging.

Comment: I want to use the bridge and AP's so I thought all products from the same manufacturer is the best option.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe this wasn't possible at the time you wrote, but if I'm understanding the question correctly, it is now. You can use the UniFi Wireless Uplink setting to choose an AP to act as an uplink, after which the UniFi AP set to use a wireless uplink will have connectivity via the selected uplink.

Comment: This is no longer true as of 2018. https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002262328-UniFi-Feature-Guide-Wireless-Uplink talks through this exact scenario -- I have done it, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If your desired physical layer diagram is:
Router <-wire-> Device <-radio-> Device <-wire-> PC

Then you're looking for transparent bridging.

The appropriate inexpensive Ubiquiti devices for that are the [Ubiquiti Airmax](https://airmax.ubnt.com/) line; you can get all AC (NOT compatible with standard 802.11ac) or all M (802.11n compatible) equipment for ideal matches; or, with an AC line as the access point, M devices can act at stations if the AP is configured that way.  Definitely choose the 5Ghz options.

I personally use elements of this product line to punch through walls and floors indoors.  Note that the narrower the beam/higher the gain, the more sensitive they are to aim.

Make sure to crank the power way down if at all possible.  The newest generation Airmax devices do provide spectrum analysis tools to help you pick the best frequency and bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up most (recent) Unify APs to act as clients now via their [Wireless Uplink](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002262328-UniFi-Feature-Guide-Wireless-Uplink) feature. The linked article walks through how to do it, and the supported hardware. I have done it with an old UAP-AC-lite acting as a client with a UAP-AC-PRO as the uplink AP.

Comment: From my understanding, this is only a partial solution to the OP's question. The OP wants to use a wired port of the second AP to connect the PC. While this feature allows you to extend wireless coverage, it doesn't create a bridge between two wired networks.

Comment: It does, I use it that way today. The only purpose I use the bridged AP for is connecting another wired network! My setup is almost exactly the diagram in the initial question.

Comment: While the capability may be present, the linked documentation doesn't address anything other than how to set up wireless uplink for AP uplink (i.e. a mesh network). It does not address at all how to bridge a connection for a device connected to a wirelessly connected AP.  Nor does your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but tech changes, and this is still a high google result.

I can confirm that the AP wireless up-link feature will allow what you're trying to attempt. You should know that the ports on the AP are bridged to the port it's up-linking to.

I have(all unifi):
USG-4p - wire - 16portPOE switch - wire - AP-HD - Radio - AP-AC-Pro - WireToPoeIn - 8portPOE switch - wired entertainment devices

The 8port switch lets me set a vlan for each of the devices, where as before everything would show as if it was directly connected to the AP-HD's port on the switch using the ALL/native vlan. I also overrode the 5ghz wlans on the AP-AC-Pro so they would not broadcast, but left the 2.4ghz on. Get ~350/400mbs speed test from a device plugged into the 8port.

Comment: This actually says that the devices can be used in the way the OP wants, but the original problem of whether or not it works through the floor of the site remains.

Comment: My Ap-HD is upstairs, and my AC-PRO is downstairs. Sorry I missed that in my answer.

Comment: Right, but different buildings have different construction in the floors, and it may or may not work in any particular building.

Comment: Obviously, but proven functionality means it's not a ruled out possibility. Ymmv is true of anything.